# VSCode: Hide Folder Containing Brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I hide a folder containing brackets in its name from my workspace in VSCode? I have tried the following, along with several attempts to escape the brackets, but nothing works. Is this even possible?

```
"settings": {
    "files.exclude": {
        "[ IsoRoot ]": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is special glob syntax to match any one of a list of characters between the braces
so if you would like to match a brace:

`left brace: [[]`

`right brace: []]`

`"[ IsoRoot ]": "[[] IsoRoot []]"`